# Shutdown Spring-Integration with Jms InboundAdapter

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-integration

My Spring Integration project doesn't shut down. In my IDE (IntelliJ) the STOP button is not sufficient. I have to use the kill (skull) button to shutdown the application.
I think it is related to running threads which did not finish yet.
So, I disabled all `MessageSource` beans (Jms inbound adapters).
And indeed, this worked: the application shuts down properly.

I tried to debug the proces, hoping for a remaining Thread in the debugger Threads view. But nothing is left there (after pressing 'stop', but before pressing 'kill').

This is the log (**with jms messagesource beans**) after hitting 'stop':

```
2017-08-11 11:51:49,089  INFO org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBeanExporter: Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2017-08-11 11:51:49,090  INFO org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBeanExporter: Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
2017-08-11 11:51:49,091  INFO org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter: Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2017-08-11 11:51:49,091  INFO org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter: Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
2017-08-11 11:51:49,092  INFO org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler: Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
```

Followed by 'kill' I get:

```
Disconnected from server
```

The log (**without jms messagesource beans**) after hitting 'stop':

```
2017-08-11 11:48:27,432  INFO org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBeanExporter: Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2017-08-11 11:48:27,432  INFO org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBeanExporter: Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
11-Aug-2017 11:48:27.463 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [myapp] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
2017-08-11 11:48:27,432  INFO org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter: Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
11-Aug-2017 11:48:27.463 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [myapp] registered the JDBC driver [oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
2017-08-11 11:48:27,432  INFO org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter: Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
11-Aug-2017 11:48:27.463 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [myapp] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@59d61fb3]) and a value of type [java.lang.Class] (value [class oracle.sql.AnyDataFactory]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
2017-08-11 11:48:27,447  INFO org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler: Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
11-Aug-2017 11:48:27.463 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [myapp] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@30aaad16]) and a value of type [java.lang.Class] (value [class oracle.sql.TypeDescriptorFactory]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
2017-08-11 11:48:27,447  INFO org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean: Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
11-Aug-2017 11:48:27.463 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
11-Aug-2017 11:48:27.641 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
11-Aug-2017 11:48:27.642 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
11-Aug-2017 11:48:27.650 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Disconnected from server
```

I think this is due to *scheduled* message polling on those JMS adapters. Do I have to kill them manually?

BTW: I tried waiting for >15 minutes but that has no effect.

**EDIT** - as requested by @ArtemBilan more of the code I used.

```
private String jmsOutbound = "QUEUE_NAME_IN_ORACLE";

@Bean
public DataSource oracleDataSource() throws SQLException {
    OracleDataSource dataSource = new OracleDataSource();
    dataSource.setURL(this.dataSourceURL);
    dataSource.setPassword(this.dataSourcePassword);
    dataSource.setUser(this.dataSourceUser);
    Properties connectionProperties = new Properties();
    connectionProperties.setProperty("MinLimit", this.minLimit);
    connectionProperties.setProperty("MaxLimit", this.maxLimit);
    connectionProperties.setProperty("ValidateConnection", "true");
    dataSource.setConnectionCachingEnabled(true);
    dataSource.setConnectionCacheProperties(connectionProperties);
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public ConnectionFactory oracleConnectionFactory() throws Exception {
    return AQjmsFactory.getQueueConnectionFactory(oracleDataSource());
}

@Bean
public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    converter.setTargetType(MessageType.BYTES);
    converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
    return converter;
}


@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "loaderResponseChannel")
public MessageSource loaderResponseSource() throws Exception {
    return Jms
            .inboundAdapter(oracleConnectionFactory())
            .configureJmsTemplate(
                    t -> t.deliveryPersistent(true)
                            .jmsMessageConverter(jacksonJmsMessageConverter())
            ).destination(jmsInbound).get();
}

// and to be complete also the outbound.

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "loaderRequestChannel")
public JmsSendingMessageHandler loaderRequestHandler() throws Exception {
    return Jms
            .outboundAdapter(oracleConnectionFactory())
            .configureJmsTemplate(
                    t -> t.jmsMessageConverter(jacksonJmsMessageConverter()))
            .destination(jmsOutbound)
            .get();
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Do you have `applicationContext.close()` in the end of your app?

Comment: No I don't think so. You mean in the main()?

Comment: @ArtemBilan I use the traditional deployment (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html). Where should I place this `close()`?

Comment: Ok. I see. So, looks like that stop in the IDE doesn't call Tomcat stop. Why don't you think that is IDE problem? How does it work standalone?

Comment: Well, it could be, but as I demonstrated, the main difference is the JMS inbound bean. When enabled, shutdown is not complete. When disabled, it shutdown nicely.

Comment: @ArtemBilan I ran it as a Jar and then my problem doesn't not occur. It shuts down nicely. (With JMS inbound active). So, it can be Tomcat or IntelliJ here.

Comment: When it is as a jar, the main is your, when it is with Tomcat, that is out of your control. Can you confirm how does it work with standalone Tomcat, not from the Idea?

Comment: @ArtemBilan I just ran it in Tomcat without IDE in the middle and the problem still remains. So, the tomcat shutdown doesn't `close()` the context??

Comment: OK. So, IDEA isn't guilty here, although it may help to debug the issue. Would you mind sharing as simple app as possible to reproduce and play from our side?

Comment: @ArtemBilan Well that will be difficult. I'm using Oracle AQ under the covers. I expect that the problem is in that area. And I don't expect you to have all this running.

Comment: That's correct. But I think the problem is somewhere with the deamon threads spawned by the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`. BTW, would you mind showing the JMS Channel Adapter configuration?

Comment: @ArtemBilan i will update my question with everything grabbed together. 1 minute..

Comment: OK. I don't see anything obvious. Can you get a thread dump after stopping Tomcat to determine which threads are not finished properly? Also: how do you start `ApplicationContext` in case of `war`?